# Retrieve nested data from firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I access the website url as it is nested. I also don't know how to access the img under the Medium section either. I can access the other information no problem by the code in the provided image:

[What my firebase looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpnAI.png)

[What my code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYbtP.png)

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("artists").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { snapshot in
        var temp = [Artist]()
        for child in snapshot.children {

            if let child = child as? DataSnapshot {
                // decode json into Artist Struct
                let model = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(Artist.self, from: child.value as! [String : Any])
                temp.append(model)

               // print(model)

            }
        }
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't actually access anything in Firebase - it's a Swift struture. Please include your existing Firebase code so we can understand where the issue is. Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about that. I will update my post to include the code that decodes the jSon file

Answer (score 0):

```
Let ref = Database().database.refrence()

ref.child("TopNode").child("secondInerNode").observe(.value, with: {//stuff})
```

You write the path to the spot where you have the data and then observe.

```
TopNode
   secondInerNode
      name: value;
```

[Check the docs for more info.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have just updated my post to show that that was my current code. After reading the documentation, I am still unsure on how to pull out the nested data: the 2 img and the website. Thank you for your help

Comment: child.childSnapshot("name of what u want") justy do .somthing and it search through option for what u want